# Undefined methods for FactoryGirl transient variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I'm working with `FactoryGirl` in `version 4.4`. I'm trying to create `after(:create)` callbacks but I'm failing on evaluator variables.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :organization do

    name 'example'

    factory :organization_with_links do

      transient do
        links_count 5
      end

      after(:create) do |organization, evaluator|
        create_list(:link, evaluator.links_count, organization: organization)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

unfortunately I got

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `links_count' for  FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner:0x007fcefb1ff780>
```

according to officall factory girl guide I'm doing everything properly :https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

any advices how to make `transient variable` working?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

So the solution was to change

```
transient do
   links_count 5
end
```

to

```
ignore do
  links_count 5
end
```

Reason: Docs on master are prepared for `FactoryGirl v.5.0`. transient will wok on `5.0` release.

More reading:  http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/658