# Undefined method for factory_girl transient attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'm working on a rails 3  (`rails (3.2.13)`) application and I am using `factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)` with `rspec (2.13.0)`.

I have a `delivery` factory that looks like this

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :delivery do

    trait :assigned do
      delivery_type 1
    end

    trait :started do
      delivery_type 2
    end

    factory :delivery_with_jobs do

      ignore do
        jobs_count = 2
        duration = 10
      end

      after(:create) do |delivery, evaluator|
        create_list(:job, evaluator.jobs_count, delivery: delivery, client: delivery.client)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which i try to instantiate in my specs like this

```
let!(:delivery_with_jobs) {
        FactoryGirl.create(
            :delivery_with_jobs,
            :started,
            jobs_count: 3,
            user: user,
            current_user: user,
            account: user.account,
            client: client
        )
      }
```

The thing is I keep getting `NoMethodError: undefined method 'jobs_count' for #<FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner:0x000000079e5f00>` when running tests and also when trying to create the factory in the rails console. I was on a lower version of `factory_girl` first [and have found this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510268/undefined-methods-for-factorygirl-transient-variables/25510653#25510653). So I have tried to change the keyword to `ignore` which didn't help, so I have tried to upgrade factory girl which also didn't help.

I also get the same error when I omit the jobs_count parameter from `FactoryGirl.create(:delivery_with_jobs)`.

Am I doing something wrong? Do you have any suggestions on what could be the cause of this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined methods for FactoryGirl transient variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510268/undefined-methods-for-factorygirl-transient-variables)

Comment: I have referenced that post in my question. That wasn't the solution for my problem, which I have also mentioned in my question. The problem was in the "="s in the transient variable definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ignore/transient block should not have =s

```
ignore do
  jobs_count 2
  duration 10
end
```

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot, i checked it hundred times for a syntax error like that, but haven't noticed it...