# How can I pass attributes to an association through a trait in factorygirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

Consider the following model setup

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :detail, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :detail
end

class EbayTitleTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one  :template, as: :detail
end
```

And here is a working factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :template do
    merchant
    channel

    trait :ebay_title do
     association :detail, factory: :template_ebay_title
    end

    factory :ebay_title_template,   traits: [:ebay_title]
  end

  factory :template_ebay_title, class: EbayTitleTemplate do
    name        "eBay Title Template"
    title       "Super Cool Hat"
    sub_title   "Keeps the sun away"
    description "The best hat available!"
  end
end
```

The following works for me

```
create(:ebay_title_template)  # creates both records, creating a new Merchant and Channel for me
create(:ebay_title_template, merchant: Merchant.first, channel: Channel.first)  # creates both records with explicit channel and merchant
```

Now what I'd like to also do is pass in custom attributes to override the defaults.  Something like this:

```
create(:ebay_title_template, title: "Overwrite the title", sub_title: "Overwrite the subtitle")
```

What ends up happening is that I get the error `ArgumentError: Trait not registered: title`

Somehow FactoryGirl thinks that I'm passing in a trait or the Template factory doesn't recognize `title` as an attribute.

I've tried using transients to allow custom args to pass through the Template and using a callback in the `:template_ebay_title` factory to map the attribute to the model column like so:

```
transient do
  custom_args nil
end

after(:create) do |record, evaluator|
  evaluator.custom_args.each do |key, value|
    record.key = value
  end
end
```

And then I create like this:

```
create(:ebay_title_template, custom_args: {title: "Overwrite", sub_title: "Overwrite"})
```

This results in the error `NoMethodError: undefined method`custom_args' for #`

So either there's a way to do this and I'm doing it wrong, or I need a completely new approach. Keep in mind, there will be dozens of associations that will need to be defined as traits (or something else) so I can't possibly assign specific transients to be passed through.

*How can I achieve my goal of creating a factory that creates the parent and the polymorphic association, allowing me to pass in arbitrary attributes for the polymorphic association, and return the parent object?*

Comment: what version of FactoryGirl are you using? Apparently prior to 5.0 you need to use `ignore` in place of `transient` - source : [undefined methods for factorygirl transient variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510268/undefined-methods-for-factorygirl-transient-variables)

Comment: I'm using factory_girl_rails 4.5.  I tried `ignore` in place of `transient` and got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to pass the values within a single hash value, you need to pass them like so:

```
create(:ebay_title_template, custom_args: {title: "Overwrite the title", sub_title: "Overwrite the subtitle"})
```

Otherwise you can create new transient values, and pass them the way you are passing them now:

```
transient do     # use ignore with FactoryGirl/FactoryBot < v4.7
  title nil
  sub_title nil
end
```

When adding more attributes like above you can then iterate over the evaluator's overrides instance variable:

```
evaluator.instance_variable_get(:@overrides).each do |key, value|
  puts key, value
end
```

Hope that helps!